# How to install Puppeteer as offline

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

My host machine's firewall will not allow connecting to the internet.

So npm install will not work there.

```
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/Puppeteer failed
```

So how can I install Puppeteer in this machine? Is there any standalone installer available?

Answer (score 3):

I do the following whenever I'm on road or don't have internet access but want to use some node_modules somewhere afar.

Two ways to deal with this:

- Create the project and install all dependencies while you have the internet access, use it whenever you want.
- Install just the specific dependencies and copy the node_modules and package.json around.

I will discuss the second because both options are basically same.

First, find a computer with internet access. And then create a blank nodeJS project just for puppeteer. Copy the **whole node_modules folder** for future usage, not just puppeteer folder. Note that it will never get updated and the version is always fixed. If you want to update it, you need to do similar steps again.

Here is the steps,

```
➜  mkdir puppeteer-copy
➜  cd puppeteer-copy 
➜  yarn add puppeteer
```

On the `package.json` file, you will see a puppeteer listed as dependency, make sure you have this on your program when using this copied package. You can copy just that line if you want.

```
➜  ls
node_modules  package.json  yarn.lock
➜  cat package.json 
{
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

The reason you need the whole node_modules folder is because of some dependencies puppeteer uses,

```
➜  node_modules ls
agent-base       es6-promisify      minimatch             puppeteer
async-limiter    extract-zip        minimist              readable-stream
balanced-match   fd-slicer          mkdirp                rimraf
brace-expansion  fs.realpath        ms                    safe-buffer
buffer-from      glob               once                  string_decoder
concat-map       https-proxy-agent  path-is-absolute      typedarray
concat-stream    inflight           pend                  util-deprecate
core-util-is     inherits           process-nextick-args  wrappy
debug            isarray            progress              ws
es6-promise      mime               proxy-from-env        yauzl
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe go in a computer that does have internet access, install puppeteer inside of an npm project.(`npm init -y && npm i puppeteer`) then search through the node_modules folder that gets created and copy the puppeteer folder inside it.  Paste that into a flash drive, connect it to computer with no internet and drag and drop into your project into the node_modules folder.  I haven't tried if this works but this would be my first approach.  I'm curious as to what you are trying to accomplish with puppeteer if you have no internet though...